# Returning rows with specific ID numbers with PHP and MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having difficulty returning the correct rows with my SQL query. I want to only return rows with either 31 or 34 as their album_items.id. I want to exclude any other album_items.id from my results. The main line I'm focused on is:

```
WHERE album_items.album IN (31,34)
```

For whatever reason, even the rows that don't have album_items.id of 31 or 34 are still being returned. Here's the full query. Is it possible that I haven't used to right syntax?

```
SELECT * FROM items_table 
RIGHT JOIN items_table 
ON items_table.id=album_items.id 
WHERE album_items.album IN (31,34)
AND items_table.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR items_table.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
AND items_table.active != '0'
```

Thanks for your time,
Sarah

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a problem with the order of operations.

In you sql, you have

```
WHERE album_items.album IN (31,34)
AND items_table.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR items_table.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
AND items_table.active != '0'
```

Which is interpreted as

```
WHERE 
(album_items.album IN (31,34) AND items_table.name LIKE '%{$term}%')
OR
(items_table.description LIKE '%{$term}%' AND items_table.active != '0')
```

Most likely, the second condition is causing the extra rows.  You'll want to include parenthesis where appropriate.

Comment: Done and dusted. Thanks heaps! The parenthesis did the trick like you said.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM items_table 
RIGHT JOIN album_items 
ON items_table.id=album_items.id 
WHERE album_items.album IN (31,34)
AND (items_table.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
OR items_table.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
AND items_table.active != '0')
```

Use () to make the order correct. Now hopefully it will give you rows with id 31 and 34 only.

I think actually you are trying to do is: (joining item_table and album_table)

```
   SELECT * FROM items_table 
   RIGHT JOIN album_items 
   ON items_table.id=album_items.id 
   WHERE album_items.album IN (31,34)
   AND (items_table.name LIKE '%{$term}%' 
   OR items_table.description LIKE '%{$term}%'
   AND items_table.active != '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your query should look like this

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM items_table i RIGHT JOIN album_items a
    ON i.id = a.id 
 WHERE a.album IN (31, 34)
   AND (i.name LIKE '%{$term}%' OR i.description LIKE '%{$term}%')
   AND i.active != '0'
```